# How to save the error: Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, pixel

I'm a beginner of coding and GEE.
I'm trying to extract the NIR and Red band time series data of each pixel in the survey area with cloud masked.
However, when applying the code below I used to do this with the Landsat dataset I'm having an error: `FeatureCollection (Error) Error in map(ID=LC08_108035_20130410): Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type.`

```
var mask_clouds_landsat8 = function(image) {
  var cloudBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 4);
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask_cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
                   .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask_cloud);
};

var scale = 30
var bands = ['B4', 'B5']

var img_masked = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
  .map(mask_clouds_landsat8)

var img = img_masked
  .filterDate('2011-01-01', '2015-01-01')
  .filterBounds(polygon)
  .map(extractPixels)
  .flatten();

print(img)
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: img, 
  selectors: ['date', 'latitude', 'longitude'].concat(bands)
})

function extractPixels(image) {
  var mask = ee.Image(1) 
  var pixels = image
    .select(bands)
    .addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
    .updateMask(image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min())) 
    .updateMask(mask)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), 
      geometry: polygon, 
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
  
  return ee.FeatureCollection(
    ee.Array(pixels.values())
      .transpose()
      .toList()
      .map(function (values) {
        var properties = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(pixels.keys(), values)
        return ee.Feature(null, properties)
          .set('date', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
      })
  )
}
```

How can I extract the time series data of every pixel correctly with cloud masked?
Please help me. Sorry for my poor English and coding.